# Python create new dict with unique keys and values from old one

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, dictionary

is there any fast Python dict checker for same values. I have tried with this code but I'm stuck with it.

```
uniq= [{'id': 1, 'name': u'Mobil'}, {'id': 2, 'name': u'Mobil'}, 
    {'id': 1, 'name': u'Ikea'}, {'id': 2, 'name': u'Ikea'}]
result={}
for dict in uniq:
    for key, value in dict.items():
        result.setdefault(key,value)
print result
```

And the output in new dict would be like:

```
result = [{'id': 1, 'name': u'Mobil'},{'id': 2, 'name': u'Ikea'}]
```

With this code i get only one reslut in **result**, and that is {`'id': 1, 'name': u'Mobil'}`

Comment: So the question is to make a list of dictionaries unique right?

Comment: One common way is to convert the list to set and back to list. `list(set([1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3]))`

Comment: What if you also had `{'id':3, 'name':u'Mobil'}` and `{'id':2, 'name':u'Unique'}`? Do either of these dicts appear in "result"?

Comment: Yes it would appear in result. @AdamSmith The main key is id, if id is different append.

Comment: @marin I think the follow up on the duped answer handles this case. Also look at https://gist.github.com/NotTheEconomist/c67c7672b323668a51d3

Comment: Thx for help guys. @AdamSmith